# SFMC SSL certificate in Third Party API request

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, api, ssjs, ssl

I want to call a Third Party API that requires a SSL certificate.

How can i use a SSL certificate for these request using SSJS or Ampscript?

Comment: I don't think this is feasible. The TLS handshake's done at a lower level and handled for you transparently by your AMPScript/SSJS functions. None of them allow you to provide a certificate, as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of SFMC, there is currently no way to do this. The closest is via SSJS and the **[script.util.httprequest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformContentSyndicationScriptUtilHttpRequest.htm)** function, but from all explorations I have put into this and have seen others put in, no one has been able to successfully pass a certificate through this function. All other HTTPGET/HTTPPOST functions in SSJS and AMPScript do not have any way to do this built into the functions.

Feel free to explore the Script.Util function as maybe you can find something we have not, but I would very confidently say that it is currently not possible in SFMC.